# note board of a list item in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

of a particular

i want to programatically access `NoteBoard` of a particular list item of a custom sharepoint2010 list ..
ie you can refer  [this](http://mscerts.net/sharepoint/sharepoint%202010%20%20%20viewadd%20notes%20to%20a%20document%20or%20list%20item.aspx)  and [this](http://blog.livinganalytics.com/2010/11/note-about-sharepoint-2010-note-board.html)

can any one suggest me a way how to access it through `API` // i want to use it in a `webpart` to post some note for that particular item  using `C#` //

thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

To access the Note Board, you will need to work with the SocialCommentManager class.  See the documentation on MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.socialdata.socialcommentmanager_members

There are a number of different methods available for loading the comments.
 - GetComments(Uri) Retrieves all of the social comments created for the
   specified URL.
 - GetComments(UserProfile) Retrieves all of the social
   comments created by the specified user.
 - GetComments(Uri,
   Int32)   Retrieves all of the social comments created for the specified
   URL, up to the specified maximum number.
 - GetComments(UserProfile,
   Int32)   Retrieves social comments created by the specified user, up to
   the specified maximum number to retrieve.
 - GetComments(UserProfile,
   Uri) Retrieves all of the social comments created by the specified
   user for the specified URL.
 - GetComments(Uri, Int32, Int32)   Retrieves
   all of the social comments created for the specified URL, up to the
   specified maximum number and starting at the specified zero-based
   index.
 - GetComments(UserProfile, Int32, Int32)   Retrieves social
   comments created by the specified user, up to the specified maximum
   number to retrieve, and starting at the specified zero-based index.
 - GetComments(Uri, Int32, Int32, DateTime) Retrieves all of the social
   comments created for the specified URL and last modified after the
   specified time, up to the specified maximum number and starting at
   the specified zero-based index.

Answer (score 0):

The post marked as the answer on this forum post shows how to post notes programmatically: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/0b1ad488-7d82-42a7-b80e-c04f79794742/